# Generic timer that works in both WinForms and other apps

Tags: winforms, multithreading, design-patterns, timer

I need to write a library class that performs timing operations, and raises a tick event periodically. I need this library to be usable from both WinForms and non-WinForms applications.

The problem is that the threading model is quite different for different types of applications. WinForms apps even have their own dedicated timers, but I don;t know in advance what type of app will be calling me.

Is there an established pattern for safely raising a timer event without prior knowledge of the type of app (WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET, etc.) that will use it?

Comment: The System.Timers or System.Threading.Timers namespace are helpful - most other things in the .NET Framework are just wrappers around those two namespaces.

Comment: You just can't specify the Timer in your library, it needs to be supplied by the client code.  The threading model is monster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an established pattern for safely raising a timer event without prior knowledge of the type of app (WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET, etc.) that will use it?

There are timers that are platform neutral in the framework: [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) and [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).  However, these will both require you to handle the marshaling back to your synchronization context, as they raise their events on a threadpool thread.

You could provide this marshaling in a generic way - ie: make a "timer" class that wraps one of the above, taking a [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) as an argument.  When the timer's Tick event occurs, you could [Post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx) the data back to the context.  This is, effectively, what the Windows Forms timer does.

You'd then just create it in your UI thread and pass `SynchronizationContext.Current` to the "new timer" class.  This would work for Windows Forms, WCF, WPF, Silverlight, etc - as they all setup a SynchronizationContext on their "main"  thread.